# Telerik Custom Style not reflecting when applied to RadButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

we are using telerik control in our WPF application. I am applying custom style for telerik control but it is not working.

```
    <Style x:Key="RadButtonStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,5,3"/>
    </Style>

   <telerik:RadButton Style="{StaticResource RadButtonStyle}"
                                                       Content="Login"
                                                       Margin="5"
                                                       cmd:Click.Command=" 
   {Binding LoginCommand}" />
```

but style is not getting applied. it is actually hiding the button...

What I did: I have downloaded NugetPackage for Telerik Theme and added reference

```
     <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary   Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary   Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary   Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to base your `Style` on the implicit one using the `BasedOn` property:

```
<Style x:Key="RadButtonStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,5,3"/>
</Style>
```